# Linq to XML - Find an element

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am sure that this is basic and probably was asked before, but I am only starting using Linq to XML.

I have a simple XML that i need to read and write to.

```
<Documents>
...
    <Document>
      <GUID>09a1f55f-c248-44cd-9460-c0aab7c017c9-0</GUID>
      <ArchiveTime>2012-05-15T14:27:58.5270023+02:00</ArchiveTime>
      <ArchiveTimeUtc>2012-05-15T12:27:58.5270023Z</ArchiveTimeUtc>
      <IndexDatas>
        <IndexData>
          <Name>Name1</Name>
          <Value>Some value</Value>
          <DataType>1</DataType>
          <CreationTime>2012-05-15T14:27:39.6427753+02:00</CreationTime>
          <CreationTimeUtc>2012-05-15T12:27:39.6427753Z</CreationTimeUtc>
        </IndexData>
        <IndexData>
          <Name>Name2</Name>
          <Value>Some value</Value>
          <DataType>3</DataType>
          <CreationTime>2012-05-15T14:27:39.6427753+02:00</CreationTime>
          <CreationTimeUtc>2012-05-15T12:27:39.6427753Z</CreationTimeUtc>
        </IndexData>
   ...
 </IndexDatas>
</Document>
...
</Documents>
```

I have a "Documents" node that contains bunch of "Document" nodes.

I have GUID of the document and a "IndexData" name. 
I need to find the document by GUID and check if it has "IndexData" with some name.
If it does not have it i need to add it.

Any help would be apreciated, as i have problem with reading and searching trough elements.

Currently I am trying to use (in C#):

```
IEnumerable<XElement> xmlDocuments = from c in XElement
                                        .Load(filePath)
                                        .Elements("Documents") 
                                         select c;

// fetch document
 XElement documentElementToEdit = (from c in xmlDocuments where 
                    (string)c.Element("GUID").Value == GUID select c).Single();
```

**EDIT**

```
xmlDocuments.Element("Documents").Elements("Document")
```

This returns no result, even tho xmlDocuments.Element("Documents") does. It looks like i cant get Document nodes from Documents node.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find those docs (docs without related name in index data) with below code, after that you could add your elements to the end of IndexData elements.

```
var relatedDocs = doc.Elements("Document")
   .Where(x=>x.Element("GUID").Value == givenValue)
   .Where(x=>!x.Element("IndexDatas")
              .Elements("IndexData")
              .Any(x=>x.Element("Name") == someValue);
```

Comment: I think that should be `doc.Descendants("Document")`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var x = XDocument.Load(filePath);
// guid in your sample xml is not a valid guid, so I changed it to a random valid one
var requiredGuid = new Guid("E61D174C-9048-438D-A532-17311F57ED9B");
var requiredName = "Name1";

var doc = x.Root
           .Elements("Document")
           .Where(d => (Guid)d.Element("GUID") == requiredGuid)
           .FirstOrDefault();
if(doc != null)
{
    var data = doc.Element("IndexDatas")
                  .Elements("IndexData")
                  .Where(d => (string)d.Element("Name") == requiredName)
                  .FirstOrDefault();
    if(data != null)
    {
        // index data found
    }
    else
    {
        // index data not found
    }
}
else
{
    // document not found
}
```

Comment: hello. GUID is wrong I know, but should be treated as simple string. But I am not getting any document (doc is null) !